# Are "code-signed" windows applications less vulnerable to virus infections?

Tags: windows, certificate, code-signing

If you sign a windows (native, not .NET) application with a code signing certificate, does this somehow prevent it being subsequently infected with a virus?

Obviously if you sign an already infected file, you've got a problem...

Answer (score 2):

If the application is signed, it can't be altered without invalidating the signature. So if nothing else, it's easier to identify that the application has been tampered with.

If it were an Office document, template or add-in with signed VBA modules, then (depending on the user's macro security settings), Office would pop up a dialog alerting the user before executing the macros - or refuse point blank to execute them. (It would detect that the macros did not have a valid signature, not that the file had been tampered with). I don't think that standard applications (EXEs) work like this, though.

Comment: No, but there is a policy setting to only allow signed .exe's

Comment: Trouble is that the OS doesn't automatically display any warning that an exe has been tampered with.   You have to check the digital signature.  Even then the message and graphics are very similar to the standard not signed so it's very hard to pick out.

Answer (score 1):

Since it checks integrity of file, it would help. However, there is nothing preventing virus from stripping signature.

If more applications employ this as a measure viruses will just strip signature and infect it anyhow.

Comment: Thanks - At what point does the file integrity get checked - on every execution?

Comment: I would assume so. However, notice that a lot of things can be changed via group policy so I cannot vouch for that.

Answer (score 0):

The question is: are signed apps less vulnerable to virus infections? Simply put, no.  Viruses don't care whether the file is signed or not.  Now, you can detect better when a signed file has had its content altered so detection is somewhat better as the signature would become invalid.

I don't recommend signing someone else's exe with your signature, if you're thinking of doing that.  I tell our developers that "when you sign an app, you are saying 'I know what's in here'"  That's not the true purpose of code signing, but putting your company's name on someone else's install seems like it creates a linkage between the two that you most likely don't want.